# Why can't SQL Server handle into's in 2 parts of a script?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I noticed some behavior I found weird while editing a co-workers stored procedure:

```
    create procedure weird_behavior (@switch bit)

    as

    if (@switch = 0)
    begin
        select *
        into #tables
        from sys.tables st
        where left(st.name, 1) in ('a','b','c')
    end

    else if (@switch = 1)
    begin
        select * 
        into #tables
        from sys.tables st
        where left(st.name, 1) in ('d','e','f')
    end

    select * from #tables

    --drop procedure weird_behavior
```

you get the error:

> There is already an object named '#tables' in the database.

This seems odd to me, since only one of the `select * into` will ever run. I'm forced to rewrite it like so:

```
    create procedure weird_behavior (@switch bit)

    as

    if (@switch = 0)
    begin
        select *
        into #tables
        from sys.tables st
        where left(st.name, 1) in ('a','b','c')
    end

    else if (@switch = 1)
    begin
        select * 
        into #tables01
        from sys.tables st
        where left(st.name, 1) in ('d','e','f')
    end

    select * from #tables

    --drop procedure weird_behavior
```

This would cause headaches because sometimes the output is in #tables, and sometimes it is in #tables01.

**Question:** why won't SQL Server let me write this code?

Comment: Why not create the temp table first and then run an `insert into` command for the IF statements?

Comment: @Padwan then you've got to spell out all the columns. Not a big deal if you've got only a few columns that don't change, but using into, it will inherit properties from the original table.

Comment: But couldn't you then just put `select * from #tables` and `select * from #tables01` inside their respective IF blocks? Or just do `select * into #tables from sys.tables where 1 = 0` (which does not require you to "spell out all the columns") and then the IF blocks just run a standard insert and there is no conflict. If you want workarounds, there are plenty available. If you want to know *why* it works this way, or expect some kind of change, you'll have to contact Microsoft.

Comment: @AaronBertrand yea, I had used something similar to Martin's where clause in my own scripts. I just found this behavior odd. Sometimes it really do be like that, I guess...

Comment: This is an issue that only affects `#temp` tables - not permanent tables. A similar question is here https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/153607/estimated-plan-generation-succeeds-for-batch-creating-and-using-temp-table-but